# How to specify property to C++ pointer in ARC environment?

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I need to add C++ pointer property into my Obj-C class. The project is ARC based. I want to property to have getter and setter. But allocation of that C++ pointer can't be managed by Obj-C framework as I understand, so I need to specify weak pointer or something?

Comment: What is a C++ pointer? Do you mean a pointer to a C++ object? Show us what you tried and where your problems are.

Comment: Yes I mean pointer to a C++ object. I have tried to create methods for getter and setter to get/set iVar. But I want to access that pointer using dot notation.

Comment: ... and what did not work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C/C++ pointers, including those to C++ objects, are not subject to ARC and are handled similarly to other primitive types, such as integers. For properties this means you use `assign`. E.g.:

```
@property (assign) int *intPtrValuedProperty
```

You must manage allocation and deallocation of the referenced memory manually, just as you do in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
NSObject* arcObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];
void* arcObjectPointer = (__bridge void*)arcObject;

void* cObjectPointer = NULL;
NSObject* cObject = (__bridge NSObject*)cObjectPointer;
```

The behavior for __bridge objects is the same as for non-ARC objects. Using __bridge you tell ARC that you understand the implications and potential dangers.

Comment: But how to declare the property itself in header?